# REST API to manage users on Skype For Business

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, skype-for-business

We're using [MS Graph API to manage users](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/users) for Office 365. I just wanted to know if this API is good enough to manage users for "Skype for Business" product as well.

Also, when we query for [Subscribed SKUs](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subscribedsku_list), we do get a list of `servicePlanName`s one of which is `MCOSTANDARD`. Can you please confirm if this plan indicates "Skype for Business"? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Active Directory user accounts can be used to sign into Skype for Business. I believe Skype for Business also supports Microsoft Accounts (MSAs) which is not currently supported for management through our V1 endpoint.

Therefore, if the accounts you are trying to manage are AAD accounts, then yes MS Graph is a good way to manage them.

I can also confirm for you that MCOSTANDARD does represent Skype for Business.

MCO = Microsoft Communication Online which was the name for Skype for Business way before it was even called Lync!

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Shawn. So the V1 endpoints of MS Graph API don't support MSAs at the moment? How do we manage MSAs? Is there a separate set of endpoints? Also, is there a preference as to what sort of accounts we should manage? We already provision users for Office 365 through MS Graph APIs. Just wanting to confirm if we can do that for Skype for Business as well. Also, a similar question if you don't mind - can we use MS Graph to manage users on these products as well - Sharepoint and Exchange Online?

Comment: All Office 365 Accounts are stored in Azure Active Directory, which means AAD accounts can be used to sign into SharePoint, Exchange, Skype, OneDrive, Dynamics, and more... If you have a tenant, and you create new user accounts, those accounts should be able to sign into all of those services. However, you must note that there are user level subscriptions required for some of these services, which means that even though an account exists and signs in, it may not be allowed to actually use the service without a valid subscription.

Comment: Note here that MSAs are individual accounts, so it doesn't really make sense to me when you say you want to manage them. In AAD, your tenant is your 'company'. Therefore, it makes sense to create a bunch of public APIs which allows you to manage the users in your company quickly and easily. For individual accounts, the general expectation is that they manage their own settings. The V2 endpoint does bring support for MSA sign on and I believe management through the Graph API V2, but I do not believe the general public has access to the current MSA APIs.

Comment: Ah, when I looked up the term Microsoft Account on the website, it conveyed a meaning as if it's a universal account that anyone could use to sign-in to any MS products/services and that's the preferred way of creating accounts going forward. I missed the part that it's an account for personal users. Now it makes sense. The reason why I had to ask those follow-up questions was [Sharepoint REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx) for standalone installations looked pretty daunting and it had its own set of user (and groups) management endpoints.

Comment: Think of MSAs as '@live.com' or '@msn.com' or even '@gmail.com' etc... They are what you own as an individual, rather than what is given to you by your business. Note that some of the stuff you are seeing here with SharePoint having its own User APIs and stuff will be solved moving forward with the Microsoft Graph. Here at Microsoft, we acknowledge the fact that our API surface area was growing too quickly, and it was fragmented in different areas such as User Accounts, where SharePoint APIs would give you different data than AAD. With MS Graph, there is a single endpoint for all of your data.

Comment: Oh, so you're saying we still have to use those Sharepoint-specific APIs if we want to manage users? Also, I suspect this is only the case with standalone Sharepoint installations (2010, 2013, 2016, etc.,) and not the Sharepoint-online version which is part of Office 365. Please confirm. Also, when could we expect MS Graph to encapsulate Sharepoint APIs in the future?

Comment: MS Graph already supports SharePoint APIs, like being able to access your files, etc... See [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs). What I am saying specifically is that SharePoint Specific User APIs may contain some values that you cannot get from the AAD Graph API, and vice versa. I believe MS Graph Solves this by presenting you a union of the data you would get from the two APIs into a single "User API" endpoint. I encourage you to take a deep dive into the MS Graph documentation.

Comment: Shawn, we've been using MS Graph API for sometime now and we use it to manage Office 365 users as [documented there](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user). If you see that page, it says the User resource represents an "Azure AD (AAD) user account". However, the [Sharepoint User doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_User) says it represents a "user in Microsoft SharePoint Foundation." Which is why I ask. We're not worried about app specific features like maintaining Sharepoint files or Word documents. Sorry for stretching this.

Comment: You have reached the limits of my knowledge on those specific matters. Why not open a new thread with Graph tag and SharePoint tag?

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. I posted the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41882920/rest-api-to-manage-users-on-sharepoint) in case you'd like to take a look.